# $("# ").prop( "checked", true ); not working on ajax success

Tags: jquery, laravel

i tried to make checkbox checked or not inside using .prop . but it never working. all other things are working perfectly. i try to this .prop with different ways.  but it not working at all.

this is ajax call

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '{{ url("issues",) }}' + '/' + id + '/edit',
  method: 'GET',
  success: function(response) {

    $('#service_name').val(response.service_name);
    $('#price').val(response.price);
    $('#comment').val(response.comment);
    $('#id_edit').val(response.id);

    // make checked in edit start
    if ((response.issue_status == null) || (response.issue_status === "Issue pending")) {
      $("#issue_status").prop("checked", true);

      console.log('issue pending');
    } else {
      $("#issue_status").prop("checked", false);
      console.log('issue fixed');
    }
    // make checked in edit end
  },
  error: function(error) {
  }
});
```

this is blade file

```html
<div>
  <label class="mr-5" for="issue_status" class="form-label">Issue stage</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="issue_status" id="issue_status" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Pending" data-off="Issue fixed" data-onstyle="danger" data-offstyle="success" data-width="200" data-height="40">
  <span id="issue_status_error" class="text-danger error_show"> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: What console log is showing? "issue pending" or "issue fixed" ? is there only one `id="issue_status"` on the page?

Comment: [The code works correctly](https://jsbin.com/joculuqote/1/edit). Please include a [mcve] to demonstrate what the problem you have is. At a guess the `if ((response.issue_status == null) || (response.issue_status === "Issue pending")) {` fails. But there is no real way of knowing.

Comment: Try *debugging* your code to determine the exact cause.  If you remove the `if` does it check/tick issue_status?  ie `$('#id_edit').val(response.id); $("#issue_status").prop("checked", true);`?  What's the *exact* value of `response.issue_status`? Double check that it doesn't have any spaces, eg `console.log("          abc      ")` will *look* the same as `console.log("abc")`